# Simplifying Quantum Tensor products with coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-fourier-transform

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert#1\rangle}$I am trying to show equality of two intermediate steps in the rearrangement of the Quantum Fourier transform definition, but I do not know how to rearrange the coefficients of a tensor product.

The text claims that $$ \frac{1}{2^{n/2}}\sum_{k_1=0}^{1}\sum_{k_2=0}^{1} \cdots \sum_{k_n=0}^{1}e^{2\pi ij \left( \sum_{l=1}^n{k_l 2^{-l}} \right)} \ket{k_1 \ldots k_n} = \frac{1}{2^{n/2}}\sum_{k_1=0}^{1}\sum_{k_2=0}^{1} \cdots \sum_{k_n=0}^{1}{ \bigotimes_{l=1}^n e^{2\pi ijk_l 2^{-l}} \ket{k_l}} $$

Isolating the parts that change leaves us with $$ e^{2\pi ij \left( \sum_{l=1}^n{k_l 2^{-l}} \right)} |k_1 \ldots k_n \rangle = \bigotimes_{l=1}^n e^{2\pi ijk_l 2^{-l}} |k_l \rangle. $$ If I were to look at a small case letting $ n = 3. $ I would get the following on the left hand side, $$ e^{2\pi i j \left( k_12^{-1} + k_22^{-2} + k_32^{-3} \right) } |k_1k_2k_3 \rangle, $$ and the following on the right hand side, $$ e^{2 \pi i jk_12^{-1}} |k_1\rangle \otimes e^{2 \pi i jk_22^{-2}}|k_2\rangle \otimes e^{2 \pi i jk_32^{-3}}|k_3\rangle. $$ Is there a rule that is similar to $$ a |k_1\rangle \otimes b |k_2\rangle = ab|k_1k_2\rangle$$ that will allow me to rewrite the RHS to be equal to the LHS as desired.

I would also like to ask for reference suggestions to strengthen my understanding of tensor product algebra as well.

Comment: see edit for how to use the `ket` command. Also, the answer to the question is essentially *yes*, that is how tensor products work. Indeed, the tensor product operation is (multi)linear by *definition*, as also pointed out in the wiki:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_vector_spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding and generalising from Jitendra's answer: the key observation in this case is that you must use how scalar factors behave over tensor products.
Specifically,
$$ a (U \otimes V) = (aU) \otimes V = U \otimes (aV), $$
or more generally
$$ a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k \,(U_1 \otimes U_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes U_k)
= (a_1 U_1) \otimes (a_2 U_2) \otimes \cdots \otimes (a_k U_k). $$
Let's consider the left-hand side of the expression which you isolated,
$$
 \exp\bigl(2\pi ij \sum_{\ell=1}^n{k_\ell 2^{-\ell}} \bigr) |k_1 \cdots k_n \rangle \;: $$ 
we may use the fact that $\exp(a+b+\cdots+h) = \exp(a) \exp(b) \cdots \exp(h)$ to re-express this as
$$
 = \Bigl[\, \prod_{\ell=1}^n \exp\bigl(2\pi ij k_\ell \big/ 2^{\ell} \bigr) \Bigr] |k_1 \cdots k_n \rangle \;. $$ 
We next use the fact that $\lvert k_1 k_2 \cdots k_n \rangle$ is short-hand for a tensor product of operators (state-vectors to be specific):
$$  = \Bigl[\, \prod_{\ell=1}^n \exp\bigl(2\pi ij k_\ell \big/ 2^{\ell} \bigr) \Bigr] \Bigl[\, \bigotimes_{\ell=1}^n |k_\ell \rangle \Bigr] \;. $$
Now we use the way that scalars interact with tensor products:
$$  =  \bigotimes_{\ell=1}^n \Bigl[ \exp\bigl(2\pi ij k_\ell \big/ 2^{\ell} \bigr) |k_\ell \rangle \Bigr] \;, $$
which was what we wanted to show.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't 
$$ e^{2\pi i j \left( k_12^{-1} + k_22^{-2} + k_32^{-3} \right) } |k_1k_2k_3 \rangle, $$ 
same as
$$ e^{2 \pi i jk_12^{-1}} |k_1\rangle \otimes e^{2 \pi i jk_22^{-2}}|k_2\rangle \otimes e^{2 \pi i jk_32^{-3}}|k_3\rangle. $$

The kets gets the kronecker product according to $ a |k_1\rangle \otimes b |k_2\rangle = ab|k_1k_2\rangle$ and the exponentials adds up according to $e^{x+y}=e^x.e^y$. Just keep in mind that this identity of exponential holds only if $x$ and $y$ commutes. In your case the power to which exponentials are raised are just scalar numbers and thus commutes.